# NgCordova:Uncaught ReferenceError: $cordovaOauth is not defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, ngcordova

I use ngCordova in my Cordova/Ionic app. I get this error message after building it:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $cordovaOauth is not defined

## index.html

[image: Screenshot of index.html]

## app.js

[image: app.js]
[image: app.js2]

Additionally, if I click the login button

```
<div class="button button-block button-positive"ng-controller="modalController" ng-click="facebookLogin()">Facebook Login</div>
```

I'll get another error message.

## Errors

[image: errors]

This is where the function is located

## Controller

```
.controller('modalController', ['$scope', '$ionicModal', '$firebase', '$ionicHistory', '$state', '$cordovaOauth', '$localStorage', '$sessionStorage','$location', function ($scope, $ionicModal, $firebase, $ionicHistory, $state, $cordovaOauth, $localStorage, $sessionStorage, $location) {
$ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/register.html', {
    scope: $scope,
    animation: 'slide-in-up',
    backdropClickToClose: false,
    hardwareBackButtonClose: false,
    focusFirstInput: true
}).then(function (modal) {
    $scope.modal = modal;
});

$scope.$on('$ionicView.beforeEnter', function (event, viewData) {
    viewData.enableBack = true;
    console.log(viewData.enableBack);
});

$scope.goBack = function () {
    $ionicHistory.goBack();
    console.log("back pressed");
};

/*Notice that after a successful login, the access token is saved and we are redirected to our profile.  The access token will be used in every future API request for the application.*/
$scope.facebookLogin = function () {
    $cordovaOauth.facebook("1234", ["email", "read_stream", "user_website", "user_location", "user_relationships"]).then(function (result) {
        $localStorage.accessToken = result.access_token;
        $location.path("/profile");
    }, function (error) {
        alert("There was a problem signing in!  See the console for logs");
        console.log(error);
    });
};
```

I don't understand this error, all files are in place and I made all the injections. What am I missing here?

Comment: you need to inject cordova auth in your run function too

Comment: did you refer angular.js file?

Comment: @AmmarAjmal I injected `$cordovaOauth` in the .run function and it reduced the errors to one (thanks for that). I'm still getting this error though `Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $cordovaOauthProvider <- $cordovaOauth`

Sajeetharan I already refer to angular.js via `<script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a couple of days researching the solution was quickly made.

## Injecting $cordovaOauth

Injecting `$cordovaOauth` was correct. If you analyze the body of the `.run` function you'll find a `$ionicPlatform` function call, which was injected to `.run` . So it is only logical to inject `$cordovaOauth`, +1 for that.

## Add ngCordova in your module

This is something that **really** annoys me with offical docs, they either don't update their docs properly as soon as a change was made or they become sloppy when it comes to the details. I had to add `ngCordova` in `app.module`.

This solved *this* issue but created another one.

Hope this helps